# How can I check the number of times a link was clicked?

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I have this SharePoint 2010 Link Library . I tried to run the custom audit log report, however what I got was something like this

```
document id         item id       user .....
{sdf87g6adsf}      {gsd87g6sd }  jgjdg
       ............
```

This ids not make any sense for me. The links are NOT documents. So , how do I know what item id belongs to what link ?

My task is simple: **I need to find out how many times each of my links was clicked**

*(PS the links are to external folders on the shared drive, not to SP pages)*

Comment: Maybe you can use IIS logs for this.

Comment: Do I have to install SP server. Because I am not allowed to install it. If yes, is there any work around. Thank you

Comment: Theres is an IIS server installed on your SharePoint FrontEnd server. You can analyze it's logs. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If it are links to external folders, your IIS logs are no use. 
You can add some javascript and bind to the click event of the links and log that in a SP list or so.

Comment: Thank You for answer. I tried adding JavaScript. However, it gets removed automatically as I save page